# PHP re-instantiate class by same name

Tags: php, singleton

this is actually a simple question but I haven't found a concise answer here.

suppose I instantiate a class:

```
$hedgehog = new Hedgehog();
```

and later instantiate it again with the same variable name:

```
$hedgehog = new Hedgehog();
```

does that simply destroy the previous instance? or is there a better way to approach this if I WANT to destroy the previous instance?  Thanks

Comment: Yes, it destroys the previous instance

Comment: @Sal00m is right it will override the previous object

Comment: would it be better to say $hedgehog = NULL; first?

Comment: Afaik, doesn't mind, the garbage collector will remove the previous instance from memory

Comment: Luckily, PHP handles all those stuff for you :). If you would work in C++, you would have to take those steps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The process of removing unused scalars, arrays and objects is called **garbage collection**.

PHP's GC is based on reference counters. As soon as there is no more reference to a *zval* (internal structure storing variables), it *may* be removed by the garbage collector.

A nice introduction to reference counting and garbage collection is located [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.gc.refcounting-basics.php).

This basic understanding is important if you e.g. create another reference to the same *zval* (in this case your object):

```
$myHedgehog = new Hedgehog();
$yourHedgehog = $myHedgehog;
$myHedgehog = new Hedgehog();
```

In this case, the *old* Hedgehog object will stay and `$yourHadgehog` will still point to it.

More confusing even when an object references itself:

```
$myHedgehog = new Hedgehog();
$myHedgehog->father = $myHedgehog;
unset($myHedgehog);
```

In this case, you will lose access to the Hedgehog object because no more symbol points to it, but since there still is a reference to it, the garbage collector will not delete it.
This also applies to an array that has a reference to itself as member:

```
$myArray = array();
$myArray['somekey'] =& $myArray;
unset($myArray);
```

Note the `&` operator that will store a reference to `$myArray` rather than copy the array.

Comment: **In this case, the old Hedgehog object will stay and $yourHadgehog will still point to it.** This is not correct. You copy your variable and put it into a new variable with all the same data. it is **no** pointer. There are no pointers in PHP.

Comment: Xatenev: You can create references to variables in PHP using `&`. These are *similar* to pointers. However, objects in PHP are **always** passed by reference.

Comment: Reference != Pointer. I am not quite sure about the second point anyways. I think PHP creates a new memory address and creates a new object, instead of passing the reference to a new variable. You would probably have to use '&' (Reference) in order to pass it by reference.

Comment: @Xatenev: read http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php for clarification. Of course, references are far from being pointers but they are as close to them as PHP allows. Objects are not exactly passed by reference, but as of PHP5, object variables hold an identifier to the real object. If an object variable is copied, the identifier is copied but still identifies the same object. For really *cloning* an object, PHP introduced the `clone` keyword.